# Does a Monk's Unarmed Movement Improvement allow vertically running on surfaces?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, movement

A monk's Unarmored Movement improvement states that the monk can now run along vertical surfaces on their turn.

Is such a "wall run" restricted to horizontal movement, or can the monk also run vertically on the wall (in order to reach the top of a tower, for instance) ?

Comment: [Related] [How much movement does a monk need to run up and stand on top of a 50-foot wall?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55985)

Comment: Does it help in understanding the movement speed game mechanic to appreciate that itIt need not be "running as an olympic sprinter does" per se, since 5e isn't that simulationist.  It 's  a matter of moving at the full rate of movement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No restrictions

Movement along vertical surfaces does not restrict the direction, but it must be "along" one plane. You can essentially treat the movement like any other movement unless the character stops it's movement or changes direction.

> ...you gain the ability to move along vertical surfaces and across liquids on your turn without falling during the move.

If you are more concerned about the word along and horizontality, the general policy in 5e is to use plain English.

> Along - moving in a constant direction on (a path or any more or less horizontal surface)

Nothing says the path moved on must be horizontal.