# What's the farthest distance one could possibly go in one round?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

Inspired by [this question,](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/does-a-monk-with-unarmored-movement-still-have-to-make-strength-checks-to-run) what is the farthest distance you can move on one turn?

Assuming you're a Wood Elf monk at level 20, you get 35 base + 30 feet *Unarmored Movement*, adding the *Mobile* feat and a casting of *Longstrider* from a friendly character, you're at 85 movement. If you're also under the effect of a *Haste* potion or spell, that increases to 170. You can now use your regular action, your extra action, your movement and your bonus action to go four times 170 feat, i.e. 680 feet.

As an Aarakocra, you would have a base flying speed of 50 - if the monk's, the *Mobile* feat's and *Longstrider's* movement increases add to this speed (and not your 25 walking speed), you would have 100 base, i.e. you could go 100*2*4=800 feet.

If those movement increases also add to *Fly's* flying speed (60), you would have 110*2*4 = 880 feet.

**Is that the farthest you could possibly go in one round? Or is a higher speed possible using some kind of spell, potion or other thing that I'm unaware of?**

For the purposes of this question, ignore the 300 flying speed you could get from *Wind Walk*, which takes 1 minute to transform (and your DM might rule that you can't dash in transformed form, or wouldn't be affected by haste).

Comment: sure it would, but I'm not asking about getting up a 1000 feet cliff, that's the other question. I'm asking about the maximum possible movement speed.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate but it is too broad just like the other question. One turn and one round are very different metrics.

Comment: @DavidCoffron while it's not an exact duplicate, the answers provided there answer my question, so I'm ok with this being closed.

Comment: That's fair, especially since in 1 round you could go arbitrarily far from other creatures pushing you etc.

Comment: Yeah, this is more or less just for fun, the 680 feet above are more than enough than you'd ever need, and they're not fully optimized. I sometimes wish I could run from my exams as fast as a fully speed-optimized 5e character ...

Comment: how far could you teleport?